# Matlab event triggering in ODE45?

Tags: matlab, matlab-guide

I have been trying to simulate a bouncing ball in Matlab, but have been unable to successfully trigger an event (probably because I'm not using the event function right?). I understand that the `value` is the value that you want to keep track of, and as soon as it crosses 0, the event will triger. `isTerminal` specifies whether you want ode45 to stop integrating and `direction` is the direction that the parameter is going when an event is triggered.

The following is my event function:

```
function [value,isterminal,direction] = ground_contact(t,y)

% Return event vectors VALUE, ISTERMINAL, and DIRECTION.
value = y(2);
isterminal = 1; %terminate the integration
direction = -1; %only trigger when moving downward
```

and here is where I actually call ode45:

```
tspan = [0 50]; % seconds
ic = [100 100 0 0]; % rad rad/s rad rad/s
m = 5; 
g = 9.81;

%% solving the ode 
options = odeset('Events',@ground_contact,'MaxStep',0.001,'RelTol',1E-10,'AbsTol',1E-10);
[t,u,TE,YE,IE] = ode45(@(t,x)pointmass_eom(t,x,m,g),tspan,ic,options);
```

Can someone tell me what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: Do you get the correct bouncing-ball behavior without the termination, first? Without knowing what's in `pointmass_eom` I'm not totally sure why you're running into issues, this looks okay to me. Your tight tolerances of `1e-10` may be an issue as well, have you tried making them something like `1e-6`?

Comment: And I assume that you've looked at the `ballode` demo supplied with Matlab? Type `edit ballode` in the command window.